# Stripe discount don't apply after prorate

Tags: stripe-payments

We use Stripe to manage our recurring payment and we are facing an issue.
To put things in context, you have to know that our customer are paying per seat and that seat quantity can change every day.

The issue we are facing is with discounts. When for example we give a 30% discount for the first year to a customer, as soon as we update the quantity, stripe apply a prorate and the discount is lost for the remaining time of the billing cycle.

According Stripe, this is the expected behavior and they don't plan to change it.
They told me to manually create invoice item to counter balance the prorate without discount.
If we do that, invoices will be getting more complex and out customer will not understand.

Does anybody faced this issue in the past ? Do you have any idea on how to handle this ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want the [usage-based price model](https://stripe.com/docs/products-prices/pricing-models#usage-based-pricing). You report the usage to Stripe and Stripe will calculate at the end of billing cycle. This way you don't need to worry about complex proration calculation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I already checked this pricing model but there are two caveats: It will be difficult to explain to our customers and we will not get the money upfront but we will have to wait for a year :(